# Why can't I return a link to a string from a function, but can I slice?

Tags: rust

I'm reading the initial Rust guide. And there it is shown that it is impossible to return a reference to a string from a function.

```
fn dangle() -> &String { // dangle returns a reference to a String

    let s = String::from("hello"); // s is a new String

    &s // we return a reference to the String, s
} // Here, s goes out of scope, and is dropped. Its memory goes away.
  // Danger!
```

But I am confused by the example from the next chapter , where the link to slice is returned from the function:

```
fn first_word(s: &String) -> &str {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();

    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return &s[0..i];
        }
    }

    &s[..]
}
```

I understand why it is impossible to return a link to a string from a function, but why is it possible to return a link to a slice in this way? because the string itself is passed by reference, or is that not the reason? I'm a beginner and I'll be glad if someone helps me understand what's going on here.

Comment: If you ask yourself for your example: When does `s` go out of scope here? Since it's externally passed via reference, it won't be dropped be the end of the function. Remember: it's borrowed, not owned be the function. So it's fine to return a reference to a "part" of it too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case you're returning a reference to a locally scoped, temporary variable. This is not fine, that value will be dropped, as noted, which invalidates any references.

In the second case you're returning a reference to data supplied in the argument with a lifetime outside of the function, so it's fine. The lifetime of the return value is the lifetime of the caller's argument, whatever that is.